# How to query a write-heavy table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, perl

I have a PostgreSQL table that records on average ~6 million records throughout the day. It take a very long time to query the table as the records are being recorded. Is there a way to create a streamer from that table where it would post new records? I want to be able to stream changes to my website as they are being recorded.

The reason it takes so long to query the table in postgres is because I have ~550 simultaneous threaded connections performing insert from different sources. Each thread does specific analysis on the data and stores information that is valuable. I scrape, quickly analyze and load the data using Perl, but building the querying from postgres table in Python.

During loading time, even if I query (read query) the table through SQL via pgAdmin:

```
select var1, var2, var3 from pg_table 
where filter = 'xyz'
```

or even

```
select * from pg_table limit 100
```

the query is very slow, meaning the results take ~4 minutes to return. When table is not being loaded with data, it takes ~3 seconds.

BTW thank you for you all your suggestions. I just ran an explain analyze on my table as it's being loaded with data. Here is the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE select count(call_option_symbol) from optionsputnik;
```

Here are the results:

```
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=357092.30..357092.31 rows=1 width=51) (actual time=342775.893..342775.893 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on optionsputnik  (cost=0.00..342868.24 rows=5689624 width=51) (actual time=0.025..341802.509 rows=5686946 loops=1)
Planning time: 415.781 ms
Execution time: 342775.974 ms
```

I will try and an index to the table, which I know will speed-up the query time but will not make interactive (process request from web, query table and return).

This is the query plan results when nothing is being written to the table:

```
QUERY PLAN
Aggregate  (cost=463634.94..463634.95 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=2326.104..2326.104 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Seq Scan on optionsputnik  (cost=0.00..445164.95 rows=7387995 width=0) (actual time=0.029..1773.378 rows=7383752 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.045 ms
Execution time: 2326.149 ms
```

Below is my table structure:

```
column_name,data_type,character_maximum_length
load_time,character,30
call_option_symbol,character,50
call_bid,double precision,
call_ask,double precision,
call_bid_ask_size,character,50
call_last,character,50
call_delta,double precision,
call_volume,double precision,
call_open_interest,double precision,
put_bid,double precision,
put_ask,double precision,
put_bid_ask_size,character,50
put_last,character,50
put_delta,double precision,
put_volume,double precision,
put_open_interest,double precision,
```

I was thinking of trying to split the table into n separate tables to reduce number of write connections at the same time. Is there anything else that I can try or test?

Comment: Why is it impossible to query the table when it is being written to? Would you update the question with that information? What happens when you run the read query? Are you using Python or Perl? Please only use the tag that relates to the technology you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am writing to postgres via Perl but trying to read from table via python. That's why I kept them there.

Comment: OK, getting there. Please update the question with what "very slow" means, and what timing you would like to achieve. "Impossible" seems to be the wrong word, since you say that read queries are working.

Comment: As in most cases: check the plan of both queries, the ones that insert the data, and the ones that select them. Sometimes the inserts can be so slow, due to some advanced checks, that the whole machine can be slow, so selects can be slow too. You can check the query plan with explain, or explain analyse https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html.

Comment: Show the table structure, the indexes, and try adding `order by something` at the end. With a proper index, it can speed up.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to re-index every time my table is update with new information?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your I/O subsystem is under stress – that would explain the time it takes.

You can gain something if you avoid sequential scans by using indexes, but that will slow down insertion considerably.

There is no free lunch here.

You could try to add enough RAM so that the table is cached, that will speed up the queries considerably.